# Test two android apps connecting with wifi

Tags: android, alljoyn

I have two android apps connected with wifi (over AllJoyn framework). Can 
I test (e.g. ping) their connection using a test framework like JUnit?

- Android simulator doesn't support wifi.
- Is there any mock object simulation wifi?
- Especially for alljoyn how can I test my app?

**Update on 19/7/2014:** I have given up AllJoyn. I had many problems. Especially multicast packets on most routers are blocked. And since I cannot modify every router my app is useless with AllJoyn.

Comment: make any http request and check its response code ..

Comment: waw @Mike Argyriou.... have you understand the (alljoyn) library clearly? That's good.. I'm still reading the materials and found lots of confusion....

Comment: alright @ASP, i'll let you know if i found any confusion again.... :D

Comment: Interesting to know that it requires multicast.